# How to generate a counter for finding a hash with 9 leading zeroes

Tags: python, multithreading, hash, mining

I'm trying to create a function that will generate a hash using sha1 algorithm with 9 leading zeroes. The hash is based on some random data and, like in concurrency mining, I just want to add 1 to the string that is used in the hash function.

For this to be faster I used map() from the Pool class to make it run on all my cores, but I have an issue if I pass a chunk larger than range(99999999)

```
def computesha(counter):
        hash = 'somedata'+'otherdata'+str(counter)
        newHash = hashlib.sha1(hash.encode()).hexdigest()     
        if newHash[:9] == '000000000':       
            print(str(newHash))
            print(str(counter))
            return str(newHash), str(counter)   

if __name__ == '__main__':

    d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Start timestamp" + str(d1))

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    p = Pool()
    p.map(computesha, range(sys.maxsize) )
    print(return_dict)
    p.close()
    p.join()

    d2 = datetime.datetime.now()  
    print("End timestamp " + str(d2))
    print("Elapsed time: " + str((d2-d1)))
```

I want to create something similar to a global counter to feed it into the function while it is running multi-threaded, but if I try range(sys.maxsize) I get a MemoryError (I know, because i don't have enough RAM, few have), but I want to split the list generated by range() into chunks.
Is this possible or should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Alin and welcome to stackoverflow.

Firstly, **yes, a global counter is possible**. E.g with a [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) or a [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) which is passed to the workers. However, fetching a new number from the global counter would result in locking (and possibly waiting for) the counter. This can and should be avoided, as you need to make A LOT of counter queries. My proposed solution below avoids the global counter by installing several local counters which work together as if they were a single global counter.

Regarding the RAM consumption of your code, I see two problems:

1. `computesha` returns a `None` value most of the time. This goes into the iterator which is created by `map` (even though you do not assign the return value of `map`). This means, that the iterator is a lot bigger than necessary.
2. Generally speaking, the RAM of a process is freed, after the process finishes. Your processes start A LOT of tasks which all reserve their own memory. A possible solution is the `maxtasksperchild` option (see the documentation of [multiprocessing.pool.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)). When you set this option to 1000, it closes the process after 1000 task and creates a new one, which frees the memory.

However, i'd like to propose a different solution which solves both problems, is very memory-friendly and runs faster (as it seems to me after N<10 tests) as the solution with the `maxtasksperchild` option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime
import multiprocessing
import hashlib
import sys

def computesha(process_number, number_of_processes, max_counter, results):
    counter = process_number # every process starts with a different counter
    data = 'somedata' + 'otherdata'

    while counter < max_counter: #stop after max_counter jobs have been started
        hash = "".join((data,str(counter)))
        newHash = hashlib.sha1(hash.encode()).hexdigest()
        if newHash[:9] == '000000000':
            print(str(newHash))
            print(str(counter))

            # return the results through a queue
            results.put((str(newHash), str(counter)))
        counter += number_of_processes # 'jump' to the next chunk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # execute this file with two command line arguments:
    number_of_processes = int(sys.argv[1])
    max_counter = int(sys.argv[2])

    # this queue will be used to collect the results after the jobs finished
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    processes = []
    # start a number of processes...
    for i in range(number_of_processes):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=computesha, args=(i,
                                                             number_of_processes,
                                                             max_counter,
                                                             results))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    # ... then wait for all processes to end
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # collect results
    while not results.empty():
        print(results.get())
    results.close()
```

This code spawns the desired `number_of_processes` which then call the `computesha` function. If `number_of_processes=8` then the first process calculates the hash for the counter values `[0,8,16,24,...]`, the second process for `[1,9,17,25]` and so on.

The advantages of this approach: In each iteration of the while loop the memory of `hash`, and `newHash` can be reused, loops are cheaper than functions and only `number_of_processes` function calls have to be made, and the uninteresting results are simply forgotten.

A possible disadvantage is, that the counters are completely independent and every process will do exactly `1/number_of_processes` of the overall work, even if the some are faster than others. Eventually, the program is as fast as the slowest process. I did't measure it, but I guess it is a rather theoretical problem here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! Then consider to `accept` this answer, @AlinGabrielEremia!